# Specializing Iterations of Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition with an Oracle

Tags: linear-programming, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

This arises from an engineering problem I am working on. Let $\mathbf{c}_i,\mathbf{a}_i\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a given set (collection) of vectors where $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Define the bounded polyhedrons (indexed over $i$)
$$
\mathcal{Q}_i\,=\,\{\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^d ~\lvert~ \mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{x}_i\leq \mathbf{b}_i,~\mathbf{x}_i\geq 0 \}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ is a matrix and vector defining the bounded polyhedron $\mathcal{Q}_i$ (over all $i$) with appropriate dimensions and assume their interiors are non-empty. Now, consider the optimization problem ($\alpha$ is a positive constant)
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}_i} ~&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{c}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i ~\\
~~&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i~\leq~\alpha \\
~~&\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathcal{Q}_i~,~~\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}
\end{align}
You can see that this can be converted to the standard input form for the Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition (DWD). Due to the properties of $\mathcal{Q}_i$, it turns out that I can assume access to an oracle that can solve the collection of $n$ subproblems extremely fast compared to a standard LP solver
\begin{align}
\max_{\mathbf{x}_i} ~&\mathbf{c}_i^T\mathbf{x}_i ~\\
~~&\mathbf{x}_i\in\mathcal{Q}_i~
\end{align}
Given the Oracle, how should I modify the steps of DWD? can you please provide the details?

I can also assume that the oracle is extremely fast at giving the extreme points of $\mathcal{Q}_i$. Given these two facts, can I further specialize the iterations of DWD. Do you mind providing the steps of the DWD then?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392133/iterations-of-dantzig-wolfe-decomposition-for-a-simple-linear-programming-proble

Comment: @RobPratt can you please help?

Comment: Not sure how to help here. The steps are the same as traditional DWD, iterating between master LP solves and subproblem LP solves, except that for the subproblems you will call your oracle instead of a standard LP solver.

Comment: @RobPratt do you mind pointing to a good reference in this regard?

Comment: The trouble I see that most algorithms I see are some variations of the simplex method using column generation which doesn't need the oracle. So I was curious how to change the iterations of Dantzig-Wolfe to use the oracle logic.

Comment: See Chapter 26 of Chvatal's *Linear Programming* (1983).  Chapter 17 of *Network Flows* (1993) discusses DWD in the context of the minimum-cost multicommodity flow problem, which was the motivating application, having block-angular structure with network blocks.